# Bellman Ford Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

The Bellman Ford algorithm scans the graph at most $|V|-1$ times. But, is there a graph that requires **exactly** $|V|-1$ iterations? If yes, can you give an example of such graph?
Thanks.

Comment: How about a complete graph? Disclaimer: I didn't check it personally, just saying intuitively :)

Comment: If the vertices are $1, 2, \ldots, n$ and the edges are $(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), \ldots (n-1, n)$, the  algorithm won't find the distance from $1$ to $n$ in less than $n-1$ iterations.

Comment: Pseudocode:
for i=1 to |V|-1 do:
    for each edge (u,v) in the graph do:
        relax(u,v)
Bellman ford algorithm doesn't need |V|-1 iterations on the graph to finish! at i=1 it could finish and doesn't need to continue ... wrong example.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz We're talking about directed graph.